# Testdome Vue question - working locally but not passing test

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am practicing for a vue TestDome test this week. One of the practice questions is as follows :

An image gallery is a set of images with corresponding remove buttons. This is the HTML code for a gallery with two images:

```
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/aff5c408-79f8-4220-9769-8b4cde774c98.jpg">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/dbd97d8f-cc11-48bd-bf21-b8762a39a55e.jpg">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Implement the image-gallery component that accepts a links prop and renders the gallery described above so that the first item in the links prop is the src attribute of the first image in the gallery. It should also implement the following logic: When the button is clicked, the image that is in the same div as the button should be removed from the gallery.

The component should be usable with any root Vue instance.

For example, after the first image has been removed from the gallery above, it's HTML code should look like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/dbd97d8f-cc11-48bd-bf21-b8762a39a55e.jpg">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my solution, which when run locally, renders the two images and buttons, as well as deletes them when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <image-gallery :links="links" @remove-link="removeLink"/>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Create image-gallery component that accepts link prop
    Vue.component('image-gallery', {
      props: ['links'],
      template: `
      <div>
        <div v-for="link in links" class="image">
          <img :src="link" />
          <button @click="removeLink(link)" class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      `,
      methods: {
        removeLink (link) {
          this.$emit('remove-link', link)
        }
      }}
    );
    
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data () {
        return {
          links: ['https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/aff5c408-79f8-4220-9769-8b4cde774c98.jpg', 'https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/dbd97d8f-cc11-48bd-bf21-b8762a39a55e.jpg']
        }
      },
      methods: {
        removeLink(link) {
            this.links = this.links.filter(l => l !== link)
        }
      }
      }
    );
    
    // Example case
    let firstButton = document.querySelectorAll("div.image > button")[0];
    if(firstButton) {
    firstButton.click();  
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => console.log(document.getElementById("app").innerHTML));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The results according to testdome:

Example case: Wrong answer
ImageGallery will render the correct list: Correct answer
Remove a single image: Wrong answer
Remove multiple images: Wrong answer

Run OK, but 3 out of 4 test cases failed.

Output:

```
<div><div class="image"><img src="https://www.testdome.com/files/resources/12362/dbd97d8f-cc11-48bd-bf21-b8762a39a55e.jpg"> <button class="remove">X</button></div></div>

Unless I am reading the question wrong, the result is correct. What am I missing?
```

Comment: What is the criteria for "Example case"? Where do you "Remove multiple images"?

Comment: "The component should be usable with any root Vue instance." ... that, to me, implies it should not need the `removeLink` method - at least that's how I read it

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to click on the button programatically. Maybe you should let the test do that. Anyway, the implemented logic seems to be on par with the request. You should take this to whoever is responsible for testing you. It's probably some technicality related to how their test bot checks DOM.

Comment: The example case code is part of the test. That is how they check that the code is functioning. I did not write the part where it clicks the button programatically, this is how they test it.

Comment: Jaromanda X was right, I had to put the function in the component so it be "usable with any root Vue instance." Once I put the method in the component rather than emitting it, the code passed all tests. Thanks for your help guys.